# How to pull a wordpress site through <iframe> while being on the same site and avoid infinite loop?

Tags: loops

I am trying to create a testing site for clients where they can change the resolutions of the site by pressing one of the icons in the header.

I've added the icons and wrote jQuery that changes width of the main-wrapper.

However since the site is based on bootstrap, the responsive part wont work since it's not firing off any media queries so i figured to wrap it all in an iframe and by reducing iframe width media queries should work.

The problem I am having is that by putting

```
<iframe src="index.php">
</iframe>
```

creates **infinite** loop. I've tried putting in in the header.php, page.php, content-page.php and each time it just keeps on loading iframes.

How do you pull entire wordpress site through iframe to use it on the same site?

Comment: I think you are looking for something similar to Responsinator?

Comment: I know that this doesn't really answer your question, but instead of what you're trying to build have you considered just telling your client about the responsive preview modes in browsers e.g. Ctrl+Alt+M in Firefox?

Comment: Thanks, I've just checked it out. Yes, I have this functionality but as far I see they are also pulling other sites onto their site via iframes. Which means I would have to either tell clients to go on this site or build one myself and make clients enter their site's url.

What i need is to have site pull itself via iframe :) If it's possible.

Comment: You are trying to something very weird: a web page that embeds to itself. I think you should reconsider the approach you are following; for example, build that test on a test site; why you would want to build a test site inside the client site itself?. Also, note that your problem and question has nothing to do with WordPress specifically; I think it is a question more suitable for StackOverflow than WPSE.

Comment: @SixfootJames +1. For the lazy: [responsinator.com](https://www.responsinator.com/)

Comment: I think solution like [Switcheroo](https://github.com/OriginalEXE/Switcheroo) will solve your issue.